# Image gets broken when exporting a table to word doc in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to export data inside a panel to word doc in asp.net 4.0

I am able to achieve the result of exporting the whole content to word, but i am getting broken image for a box i am using in the .aspx page.

My .aspx page :

```
    <asp:Panel ID="tblReport" runat="server">
<div class="boxed1a">
                <img class="images4" src="images/AoAFund.png" width="640" height="45" />
                <table class="tb3">
                <tr>
                <td>Leasehold & Functional Programs</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLFP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtNA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Acquis Maint & Renov</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAMR" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

and my code-behind to export this panel to word:

```
protected void btnWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=report.doc");
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    tblReport.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

here is the word doc screen shot :
[image]

Any clue how to remove the broken image or fix it ? I googled a lot but not clear of any good answers.

Comment: When do you get the broken image? Whenever you view the page, or only after your code runs?

Comment: @Melanie : Viewing the page in .aspx renders fine, but when i export it to word doc, the images get broken, but MehdiKaramosly's answer fixed my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I exactly run into the same problem few days ago, instead of :

```
src="images/AoAFund.png"
```

try to mention the full url like :

```
 src="http://server_host/images/AoAFund.png"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Genius!! :) thnx a lot, worked on this problem for about 2 hours, and your answer worked flawlessly !! thanks @Mehdi Karmosly

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it fixed your problem, you can mark my post as the solution.